# keyboard layout on English keyboard for Utsaah hindi font

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-languages, truetype-fonts

I want to know where can I get Hindi keyboard map for Utsaah hindi font.

I know typing in Hindi with Kruti dev font using English keyboard.

[url][https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/utsaah[/url]](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/utsaah%5B/url%5D)

this is the font I have to learn to type.

Typing in different hindi font needs different keyboard map so I searched on internet but I could not get

keyboard layout on English keyboard for Utsaah hindi font.
I have US English Remington keyboard but hindi key bindings for Utsah font I could not search.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboards/kbdinhin.html

Answer (score -1):

It is a font and not a keyboard.

To enter below characters use Alt+ and in some programs enter the hex number and pressing without the `0x` and press Alt+X or Alt+Shift+X.

```
2406    0x966   ०   Number  / Devanagari
2407    0x967   १   Number  / Devanagari
2408    0x968   २   Number  / Devanagari
2409    0x969   ३   Number  / Devanagari
2410    0x96A   ४   Number  / Devanagari
2411    0x96B   ५   Number  / Devanagari
2412    0x96C   ६   Number  / Devanagari
2413    0x96D   ७   Number  / Devanagari
2414    0x96E   ८   Number  / Devanagari
2415    0x96F   ९   Number  / Devanagari
```

If you want to type on a Hindi keyboard install the correct keyboard. Click the language indicator next to the time on the taskbar.

You can use the on screen keyboard (next to language in taskbar) in each language to see what letters map to what key.

Comment: Can you give a link to correct keyboard software that can be installed.